# SOAP error in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, soap

I am trying to add a SOAP service using VS 2005 via add web reference. However when I add the reference, I get all options disabled and the following error. What am I doing wrong?

The document at the url http://interface.postcodechecker.co.uk/wsdl/pccInterface.wsdl was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:

- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL http://interface.postcodechecker.co.uk/wsdl/pccInterface.wsdl could not be found.'.

  - The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'application/wsdl+xml').
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (73, 30).'.

  - Namespace prefix 'soapenc' is not defined.
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be  and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like they fumbled the schema.  Save the .wsdl to a file and open it in a text editor.  Add two lines to the header so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="Postcodes"
   targetNamespace="http://interface.postcodechecker.co.uk/wsdl/pccSOAP.wsdl"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns="http://interface.postcodechecker.co.uk/wsdl/pccSOAP.wsdl"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> 
   <types>
   etc...
```

The two added lines are indented, note that the angle bracket was moved.  Then just load the service reference from the file.

Comment: Tried that too, but to no avail. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Worked fine on my machine.  Contact the company if you need support.

Comment: yea ... sent them an email ... meanwhile I would try this again ... perhaps I am missing something else

Comment: It worked after I changed it again ... apparently there was some glitch when I had changed it the first time and I hadnt saved it correctly. Thanks !

Comment: I am wondering if you hav ne idea about a new error thats been popping up recently. (Unable to import binding 'pcc_Binding' from namespace 'http://interface.postcodechecker.co.uk/wsdl/pccSOAP.wsdl')
Seems odd